# Use one instance in multiple components with Autofac

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, inversion-of-control, autofac

So I have an `IApplicationDbContext` class and an `ApplicationDbContext` class that implements it. In the code written by me I use `IApplicationDbContext`, but higher up on the chain MVC uses `ApplicationDbContext` and I can't really change that, so at the moment I have registered components like this:

```
builder.RegisterType<ApplicationDbContext>()
       .AsSelf()
       .InstancePerRequest();
builder.RegisterType<ApplicationDbContext>()
       .As<IApplicationDbContext>()
       .InstancePerRequest();
```

Which isn't ideal, because I have essentially two instances of the same thing. Is it possible to do something like this?

```
var dbContextInstance = new ApplicationDbContext();
builder.RegisterInstance(dbContextInstance)
       .As<ApplicationDbContext>()
       .InstancePerRequest(); 
builder.RegisterInstance(dbContextInstance)
       .As<IApplicationDbContext>()
       .InstancePerRequest();
```

So whenever a constructor needs `ApplicationDbContext` it uses the `ApplicationDbContext` instance and whenever it asks for an `IApplicationDbContext`, it gets that same `ApplicationDbContext` instance. In the end there is only one instance, but it is used for multiple types. Can I do this somehow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A registration can target more than one service. I would recommend something like this :

```
builder.RegisterType<ApplicationDbContext>()
       .AsSelf() 
       .As<IApplicationDbContext>()
       .InstancePerRequest();
```